# Confusing message when I try to award a bounty

Tags: feature-request, bounties, user-interface

When awarding a bounty to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12220859/418872), I got this message:

[image: Confirmation message]

I clicked OK and expected that the bounty will get immediately awarded. Instead, I got this orange box:

[image: This should be displayed before the confirmation message]

I suppose the reason is that to award bounty, at least 24 hours must pass from the moment it was started. That's cool, but in cases like mine, I would expect to see the orange box *only* - the "Are you sure" dialog should be displayed only if it is actually *possible* to award the bounty.